# Помогите понять как машина читает простую рекурсию:

Tags: javascript

Вот я понял из разных примеров, что компьютер смотрит на условие в if - если оно выполнено, то возвращает то, что в нем прописано. Это база рекурсии. Далее он смотрит else, где указана эта же функция, которая будет выполняться до тех пор, пока желаемое условие не станет удовлетворять базу рекурсии. Так?
Но:
1)тогда почему данный код работает? Ведь if обязан возвращать цифру "1" всякий раз, как условие будет выполняться. Ведь "return 1".
2)почему n приходит к 1, если он все время будет плюсоваться к n и отнимать минус один. Разве это не бесконечный цикл? Или в данном случае тут играют роль две разные "n". Объясните плиз. Оч хочу понять это.

```js
function sumTo(n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return n + sumTo(n - 1);           
  }
alert(sumTo(10));
```

Comment: кажется до меня кое-что доходит. Правильно ли я полагаю, что при рекурсии else тупо накладываются друг на друга? Т.е. происходит следующее:    return 3 + sumTo(3 - 1) + return 2 + sumTo(2 - 1) + return 1 + sumTo(1 - 1); и в итоге происходит: (return 3+return 2+ return 1) - в одном месте, и отсчет(3-1, 2-1, 1-1) в другом?

Comment: на каждом шаге рекурсия функция вызывается с меньшим аргументом

Comment: Вам надо пройтись по шагам в дебаге, тогда поймете. Наверное...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)тогда почему данный код работает? Ведь if обязан возвращать цифру "1" всякий раз, как условие будет выполняться. Ведь "return 1".

изначально n равен 10, поэтому данное условие не выполняется `if (n == 1) return 1;` (10 не равно 1)

> 2)почему n приходит к 1, если он все время будет плюсоваться к n и отнимать минус один. Разве это не бесконечный цикл?

n не "плюсуется". Как можно видеть в данной строке кода `return n + sumTo(n - 1);` в `sumTo` передается `n - 1`, соответственно в `sumTo` будут передаваться следующие параметры на каждой "итерации": 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Когда n будет равно 1, то выполнится условие выхода из рекурсии и последний вызов вернет 1 (`return 1;`)

Пример на `sumTo(3)`:

1. n равно 3

- условие не выполняется, так как n !== 3
- функция возвращает 3 + sumTo(3-1)

2. n равно 2

- условие не выполняется, так как n !== 2
- функция возвращает 2 + sumTo(2-1)

3. n равно 1

- условие выполняется, так как n === 1
- функция возвращает 1

дальше все эти значения собираются обратно и выходит 1 + 2 + 3. Они собираются так как все вызовы функций возвращали новые функции с декрементированными значениями, и только когда условие выполнилось функция вернула примитивное значение (единицу), но все функции замкнуты с остальными значениями, которые нужно "собрать"

P.S. Я пытался) если что-то не так написал - поправьте меня в комментариях

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если придираться, `• функция возвращает 3 + sumTo(3-1)` ну не прямо возвращает, а 'должна вернуть', но пока не может: Сперва нужно дождаться результата sumTo(2).

Comment: Спасибо большое!