# Простая рекурсия JS

Tags: javascript, функции, рекурсия

Всем добрый день.

Пожалуйста, опишите принцип работы простой рекурсии.
Не могу понять как при рекурсии браузер понимает, что нужно умножать именно
base * base, а не, к примеру, base * exponent. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
function power(base, exponent)
{

       if(exponent == 0)
       {
           return 1;
       }
       else
       {
           return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
       }
   }
```

Comment: Все, разобрался. Как я понял при первой рекурсии происходит следующее:
base * base , где второй base это возврат значения вызова рекурсии в первый раз.
Т.е. значение base во внешней функции меняется при возврате значения внутренне рекурсии, а при вызове рекурсии значение из внешней рекурсии попадает во внутреннюю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите понять как машина читает простую рекурсию:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239165/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e)